The problem of importing tensorflow - load_model
I am a beginner in python development and I have a problem in my code.
My task is to make a website and connect a trained model to it.
The problem is that when importing load_model, the following error occurs Unresolved reference 'load_model'
I am using the python 3.9 virtual environment in PyCharm and I already have the last version tensorflow library installed, however this does not apply to load_model.
I saved the already trained model in the model_final.keras file in the same directory as app.py
I have inserted all my code below
import streamlit as st
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

model = load_model('model_final.keras')


def main():
    st.header('Header')
    st.subheader('There you can upload your files')

    uploaded_file = st.file_uploader('Upload file', type=['csv', 'xlsx', 'txt'])

    if st.button('Upload'):
        if uploaded_file is not None:
            data = pd.read_csv(uploaded_file)
            predictions = model.predict(data)
            st.write(predictions)
        else:
            st.error('Please, upload your file.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

After searching for a solution to the problem on the Internet, I came across articles where it was said that the versions of some libraries cannot work together and it is necessary to change some of them, I tried it but got no result.
I suppose the problem may be the misuse of the tensorflow library, but I'm not good at it.

“from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model” - does your actual code include the asterisks? If so, that's probably the problem

Of course not, it's a typo

My best guess is that you have an issue in your environment, i.e  you installed tensorflow in a different one than the one PyCharm uses for your project. I would recommend trying to run your project outside of the IDE, with the right virtual environment enabled, and see if you still have issues.
